# Create and update two models in one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

I would like to create a model and update one part of another at the same time.

I have two models `Order` and `Listing`. `Order belongs_to :listing` and `Listing has_many :orders`

When a user fills up the order form, an order is created. In the URL there is a parameter called `passengers` sent via `GET` method (url looks like this : `http://localhost:3000/listings/3/orders/new?passengers=2`). With this parameter I would like to update only one column of the listing model.

I tried to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :listing` to the `Order` model and change the `orders_controller`.

EDIT - PROBLEM SOLVED
solution : orders_controller :

```
@order = Order.new(order_params)
@listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
@listing.update_attribute(:passengers, params[:passengers])
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you tried?

Comment: Specifically, what you tried for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Also, you could save the `params[:passengers]` value in an instance variable in `orders#new` and then pass that value as a hidden_field in your form to the create action and then update the `Listing` object manually. This is definitely the less preferred way, though. In any case: in `orders#new`, `@passengers = params[:passengers]`. Then, in your new orders form: `hidden_field_tag :passengers, @passengers`, which will then give you `params[:passengers]` in `orders#create` so you can then update the listing manually.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. The thing is, when I call orders#create 
I have in my parameter the params[:passengers] but I don't know how to update the column "passengers" in my listing model... I tried something like this im my orders#create : @order = Order.new(order_params)

Comment: then @order.listing.passengers = params[:passengers] but in my logs the SQL insert is only execute in my order model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `@order.listing.passengers = params[:passengers]`, try `@order.listing.update_attribute(:passengers, params[:passengers])`.